# Turn off firstboot on centos

Tags: centos, centos6

Firstboot seems to be running based on this:

```
[root@master ~]# ps ax |grep firstboot
27891 pts/0    R+     0:00 grep firstboot
```

I can't seem to kill it

```
[root@master ~]# killall firstboot
firstboot: no process killed
```

When I check if it's running, the pid seems to have changed!

```
[root@master ~]# ps ax |grep firstboot
28233 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep firstboot
```

Using chkconfig doesn't work either

```
[root@master ~]# chkconfig firstboot off
error reading information on service firstboot: No such file or directory
```

Thoughts on what I can do to kill the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have interpreted this output incorrectly.

```
[root@master ~]# ps ax |grep firstboot
27891 pts/0    R+     0:00 grep firstboot
```

That is not telling you that firstboot is running. Notice the command there `grep firstboot`. That is telling you that your `grep` is running.

Try `pgrep firstboot` or `ps ax | grep '[f]irstboot'` to avoid that confusion.